# I am trying to change the colour of my text with lines inside but cant

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, text, mask

I typed the text, created outlines, edited the text, then expanded it. I then made the lines using the Blend Tool and sent that to the back. I then selected everything and clicked Make Clipping Mask. I got the result in the picture. I am trying to change the whole thing to this colour 684D43 but cannot change it.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Any idea how I would change the color?

Comment: Im on Illustrator CS6 if that helps

Comment: Must say thats extremely hard to read as-is, it hurts!

Comment: Have you tried changing just blending lines and then outline?

Comment: You need to add more details to this question. "but I cannot change it" is hardly an explanation. What have you tried? Can't you select the lines in the blend, or if you have selected them, it can't you select the colour? Although I've given an answer and have guessed what your problem might be, I'm still voting to close this as it's unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustrator frequently converts objects to grayscale. I'm not sure why, I don't argue.

Whenever I find something stuck in black and white mode I select it, open the color dialogue, click the drop down arrows in upper right and put it back to CMYK or RGB mode. The object will now show the last color effect you made or will allow you to change colors.

[image]

Comment: Excellent point @Webster. That catches me out from time to time, and might very well be the issue the OP has.

Comment: Webster thank you very much, this was the problem, which I fixed by accident shortly after posting the question but this explains what it was. Billy Kerr I'm sorry my question wasn't detailed enough. This is my first ever post on a forum and I am a complete Illustrator/Photoshop beginner and am trying to teach myself. I appreciate your feedback also and will be more specific in future.

Comment: @Bengaliwah That's fine. Not a problem. Everyone has to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the artwork you're trying to make uses a clip group with no color cutting out pieces of a shape that contains color.

Solution: Open up the  layer group in your layers panel (bottom-right) and find the shape that has color in it. Select by clicking on the circle on it's right and then change the fill color on the top-left.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the layers panel, and expand the Clip Group until you find the blend, and expand the blend to find the two lines that form it ...

Click on the Target icon to select the line, and change the colour of the stroke. You can change the colour of each stroke independently, and end up with a kind of gradient.

[image: Screenshot trageting lines within blend]